# Pythonic Version of Last Digit Of a Huge Number

Tags: python, math

I am working on the CodeWars code challenge [Last digit of a large number](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5511b2f550906349a70004e1/train/python):

> Define a function that takes in two non-negative integers  and  and returns the last decimal digit of    . Note that  and  may be very large!
>
> For example, the last decimal digit of  9<sup>7</sup> is  9, since  9<sup>7</sup> = 4782969. The last decimal digit of
> (2<sup>200</sup>)<sup>2<sup>300</sup></sup>, which has over 10<sup>92</sup> decimal digits, is 6. Also, please take 0<sup>0</sup> to be 1.
>
> You may assume that the input will always be valid.

#### My code

```
def last_digit(a, b):
    if b==0:
        return 1
    i=(a**2)%10
    j=(a**3)%10
    k=(a**4)%10
    l=(a**5)%10
    print(a,b)
    for x in [2,3,4,5]:
        n = ((b-x)/4) + 1
        if round(n,0)==n:# I believe this might be the problem.
            if x==2:
                return i
            elif x==3:
                return j
            elif x==4:
                return k
            else:
                return l
```

So my code works with all test cases except for this one.

```
last_digit(3715290469715693021198967285016729344580685479654510946723,
           68819615221552997273737174557165657483427362207517952651)
```

Earlier I tried using `if math.floor(n)==math.ceil(n)`  but still I'm getting the wrong output for this case.

#### Algorithm I used

I noticed that, the **last digit of powers** of 2,3 or any other number, when listed down in a subsequent manner, repeats after every for results:

For example:

```
(2**2)%10>>>4
(2**3)%10>>>8
(2**4)%10>>>6
(2**5)%10>>>2
(2**6)%10>>>4 # then the last digit of the next result will be 8 and so on.
```

Comment: Fyi, there's a very efficient builtin to do exactly what you want: `pow(a, b, n)` computes `a**b % n`, so `pow(a, b, 10)` is the last digit of `a**b`.

Comment: @Seon Thank you so much friend for this knowledge.
Also do you have any idea on how to modify my if statement:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple (and very fast) solution:

```
D = [(0,), (1,), (2, 4, 8, 6), (3, 9, 7, 1), (4, 6),
     (5,), (6,), (7, 9, 3, 1), (8, 4, 2, 6), (9, 1)]

def last_digit(a, b):
    if a == b == 0:
        raise ValueError('0 to the power 0 is undefined')
    return D[a % 10][(b - 1) % 10]
```

Comment: This is almost the exact same as my solution, only far, far shorter.

Comment: Look-up tables are almost always a better solution than a giant pile of `if` statements. Nice!

Comment: @Riccardo Great sol. Could you please also explain the algorithm:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `/` operator performs a floating point division. And thereby the big operand numbers will lose precision and the quotient is therefore not exact.

Instead of looping, you can use the `%` operator again to find out which of the 4 cases you are in. Also apply `%10` on `a` before applying `**`, as the result does not depend on the other digits of `a`:

```
def last_digit(a, b):
    if b==0:
        return 1
    return ((a % 10) ** ((b - 1) % 4 + 1)) % 10
```

NB: This takes into account the following instruction of the code challenge:

> Also, please take 0<sup>0</sup> to be 1.

The same with a conditional operator:

```
def last_digit(a, b):
    return ((a % 10) ** ((b - 1) % 4 + 1)) % 10 if b else 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just manually enter all the possibilities:

```py
def last_digit(a, b):
    if (b == 0):
        if (a == 0):
            return -1
        else:
            return 1
    a = a % 10
    if (a == 0):
        return 0
    if (a == 1):
        return 1
    if (a == 2):
        return [6, 2, 4, 8][b % 4]
    if (a == 3):
        return [1, 3, 9, 7][b % 4]
    if (a == 4):
        return [6, 4][b % 2]
    if (a == 5):
        return 5
    if (a == 6):
        return 6
    if (a == 7):
        return [1, 7, 9, 3][b % 4]
    if (a == 8):
        return [6, 8, 4, 2][b % 4]
    return [1, 9][b % 2]
```

This takes advantage of what you observed, that the trailing digits of the output repeat on a cycle as the exponent is incremented. That is because digits of higher value cannot affect digits of lower value in addition or multiplication.

For instance, examine the powers of 3:

> 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, ...

The last digits are the same as if took only the last digit of the number each time:

> 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, ...

Since there are only 10 digits to choose from, we must eventually hit a digit we already saw. Since each digit is calculated from the previous, one may prove that the sequence must repeat. That it must always hit one is a bit more complicated to prove, but is also true.

So, as I have demonstrated, one may just calculate these cycles by hand and then manually enter them into the computer. The computer may then calculate which sequence to choose based on the value of the base, and then which element to choose by calculating the remainder of the exponent and the length of the cycle.

If you want the function to return 1 when calculating 0 to the power of 0, just replace the `return -1` with `return 1`.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the `round`, it is because the number is simple too large. Python can store arbitrarily large integers, but it cannot with float. `n = ((b-x)/4) + 1`, here division is taking place, and division with very large numbers has always been an issue with precision, or technically, conversion to float. When you are dividing, `type(n)` command will confirm that it is being converted to `float`.

If you use an integer instead of floating-point, python will preserve all of the digits of your number no matter how long it is. But if you use a floating-point number, then it's always going to be an approximation.

You may need to change your algorithm after all, in case of not using any modules.